# Comparing Items In List using loops & conditional statements

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to loop through a list and compare the items against what a person has entered and then make a decision. Any ideas where my logic is going wrong?

```
user = input("Enter your password: ")
passwords = ["pa$$w0rd", "password123", "scr1pt1ng", "F0r3n51c5",    "123456"];

for n in passwords:
    if n == user:
        print("Found", n)
        break
    else:
        print(user, "Not Found")
```

Comment: in python 2.7 it's `print user, "Not Found"`. BUT: does it work? Do you get an error? Please tell us :) ([mcve])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read more about the difference between python2 and python3.

In your code you use python3 style:`print(something)`, because python2 style should be `print "something"`; `input` vs `raw_input`

So your version is Python3

I dont use python2, but it should be like:

```
user = raw_input("Enter your password: ")  # input changed to raw_input
passwords = ["pa$$w0rd", "password123", "scr1pt1ng", "F0r3n51c5",    "123456"];

for n in passwords:
    if n == user:
        print "Found", n
        break
    else:
        print user, "Not Found"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback TitanFighter much appreciated :)